# Counting instances of items in a dictionary (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, count

I'm trying to find the 10 most common items in a column in pandas, basically similar to using value_counts().  The problem is the column contains dictionary entries as seen here:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = pd.read_json('data/world_bank_projects.json')
print(df['mjtheme_namecode'].head())

0    [{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}, {...
1    [{'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'},...
2    [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'...
3    [{'code': '7', 'name': 'Social dev/gender/incl...
4    [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'...
Name: mjtheme_namecode, dtype: object
```

How can I order these by count(of either code #, or name)?

Comment: Since you have a list of dictionaries, why not create a new DataFrame from that column and doing our inferences on that, or at least explode it out into new columns

Comment: Thanks, I'm very much a noob (this is for a class), mind walking me through that a bit?  I assume its some use of pd.DataFrame(df['mjtheme_namecode]')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [[{'code': random.randint(0, 10), 'name': ''.join(random.sample('abcdef', 3))} for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(3)]})

                                                col1
0  [{'code': 1, 'name': 'bfc'}, {'code': 7, 'name...
1  [{'code': 7, 'name': 'cda'}, {'code': 0, 'name...
2  [{'code': 2, 'name': 'fea'}, {'code': 7, 'name...
```

Expand this out into another DataFrame:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame([val for pair in df.col1 for val in pair])

   code name
0     1  bfc
1     7  dfa
2     7  cda
3     0  cfb
4     2  fea
5     7  cdb
```

Now you can easily query this new DataFrame:

```
tmp.code.value_counts()

7    3
2    1
1    1
0    1
Name: code, dtype: int64
```

I as able to find your input data, so here is how you might apply it on that dataset:

```
outdf = pd.DataFrame([val for pair in df['mjtheme_namecode'] for val in pair])
outdf.name.value_counts().nlargest(5)

# Result
Environment and natural resources management    223
Rural development                               202
Human development                               197
Public sector governance                        184
Social protection and risk management           158
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks definitely works although the val pair thing is definitely outside of what I've learned thus far

Comment: @Zonk I added in a simple example on your actual dataset as well. The `for pair in ... for val in pair` is simply flattening a nested list of dictionaries

Comment: I'm not sure if this delves off topic but there is missing data so if we do nlargest out to 10 I  get a blank answer in the top 10.  If I changed the the .name to .value, I get the true top 10.  Is there a way to print out the name along with the code?

Comment: @Zonk try this `outdf.loc[outdf.name.ne('')].name.value_counts().nlargest(10)`  This will ignore blank entries

Comment: Thanks, this definitely solves the problem, but I was just curious if there was a way to include the 'name' column as well if I did outdf.code.value_counts().nlargest(10)

Comment: Yes, you can use `outdf.iloc[outdf.code.value_counts().nlargest(10)]`